# Add JBoss system-property with leading zero

Tags: jboss

I am trying to add a JBoss system-property by using the JBoss CLI.

```
/system-property=variable.name:add(value=%{{{variablename}}})
```

The value of `%{{{variablename}}}` is '05', but it truncates the leading zero, so the system-property gets set to '5'.
I tried to use `printf`, but the CLI doesn't know `printf` whereas running the command:

```
/system-property=variable.name:add(value=`printf "%02d" %{{{variablename}}}`)
```

leads to:

> Failed to substitute printf "%02d" 05: No command handler for 'printf'.

Any other idea how to get the leading zero into the system-property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to do it just by adding two quotation marks to the value

```
/system-property=variable.name:add(value="%{{{variablename}}}")
```

I thought it was kind of a bash problem thats why I tried the solution with printf instead of just using quotation marks.
[The JBoss documentation about system-properties](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/CLI+Recipes#CLIRecipes-Adding%2CreadingandremovingsystempropertyusingCLI) sadly doesn't mention a case like this one.